# .NET Core 6 RC1, How to Retrieve Result back when using Task.WhenAll?

Tags: c#, task, task-parallel-library, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have the following Code

```
List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(OrgLocationID))
            {
                tasks.Add(GetOrgLocations());
            }

           
            tasks.Add(GetOrg());
            tasks.Add(GetRoleTypes());
            tasks.Add(GetOrgOrLocationUserInfo());
            await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
```

How do i retrieve the results when each Task can return different data type ?
Also how may i know if the some of them failed and may not return data ?

Comment: Can you clarify what problem you have using examples for previous versions of .Net/.Net core and why you need on specific for .Net Core 6 RC1 ?

Comment: I am not comparing between .NET versions. 
Just specifying the environment where I am running code; is using .NET 6 RC1,  if don't specify obviously i expect that to come up as question down the line as to what framework am i using.

Comment: I did figure out solution , but since this is comment section , it is limiting the number of characters i can post, will wait till it enables me to write my own answer.

Comment: I'll save use the effort. If that duplicate is not what you looking for see if some other https://www.bing.com/search?q=How+to+Retrieve+Result+back+when+using+Task.WhenAll would do.

Comment: that link is helpful